# VBA - IE Crashes after macro finishes running

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I have automated some task that involve populating some boxes with information from Excel. Everything works perfect except for the fact that when the macro finishes IE crashes and stop responding and the website gets reloaded.

Any ideas of why this happens?

```html
Sub automateIE()

Dim wkb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1, ws2, ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("ws1")
    
Dim ieApp As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set ieApp = IEWindowFromTitle("website title")   'this is a formula I'm using from someone else and it's after this code
    If Not ieApp Is Nothing Then
        Set ieDoc = ieApp.document
    End If

ws2.Activate
If ws2.Range("A6").Value <> "" Then
    If ws2.Range("A6").Offset(1).Value = "" Then
        additems = 1
        GoTo add_items                           'if I want to exit the for loop with "Exit For" IE crashes too so I chenged it to GoTo
    ElseIf ws2.Range("A6").Offset(2).Value = "" Then
        additems = 2
        GoTo add_items
    Else
        additems = ws2.Range(Range("A6"), Range("A6").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
        GoTo add_items
    End If
End If

ws3.Activate
If ws3.Range("A6").Value <> "" Then
    If ws3.Range("A6").Offset(1).Value = "" Then
        additems = 1
    ElseIf ws3.Range("A6").Offset(2).Value = "" Then
        additems = 2
    Else
        additems = ws3.Range(Range("A6"), Range("A6").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
    End If
End If


add_items:
Dim additemsbtn As HTMLDivElement
Set additemsbtn = ieDoc.getElementById("MI_AddItem")
Dim aNodeList As Object
Dim itemName As HTMLDivElement
Dim savebtn As HTMLDivElement

additemsbtn.Click
Set aNodeList = ieDoc.querySelectorAll("[dojoinsertionindex]")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Dim repeatadd As Variant
Dim rest As Integer

repeatadd = (additems / 5)
Dim roundvalue() As String
roundvalue() = Split(repeatadd, ",")

If additems < 6 Then
    For i = 0 To additems
        If aNodeList.Item(i).innerText Like additems Then
            aNodeList.Item(i).Click
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Else
    If additems Mod 5 = 0 Then
        For i = 1 To repeatadd
                aNodeList.Item(4).Click
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Next i
    Else
        If additems < 75 Then
            rest = additems Mod 5
            For i = 1 To roundvalue(0)
                aNodeList.Item(4).Click
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Next i
            For i = 0 To rest
                If aNodeList.Item(i).innerText Like rest Then
                    aNodeList.Item(i).Click
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                End If
            Next i
        ElseIf additems >= 75 And additems < 100 Then
            ieDoc.getElementsByName("pageSize")(0).Value = 100
            ieDoc.getElementById("navlist").Click
            rest = additems Mod 5
            For i = 1 To roundvalue(0)
                aNodeList.Item(4).Click
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Next i
            For i = 0 To rest
                If aNodeList.Item(i).innerText Like rest Then
                    aNodeList.Item(i).Click
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If
End If

Dim element As Object
Dim loopaux As Integer
Dim loopexit As Integer
Dim valueaux As String

If additems > 20 Then
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
End If

'FROM HERE
For Each element In ieDoc.querySelectorAll("select")
    If element.Name Like "itemLevelCustomFieldValue*" Then
    Else: GoTo nextelement
    End If
    If element.Value <> "JJTMS" Then
    element.Focus
    element.Value = "something"
    element.FireEvent ("onchange")
    loopaux = loopaux + 1
    If loopaux = additems Then
    GoTo exitfor
    End If
    End If
nextelement:
Next element
exitfor:
loopaux = 0
loopexit = 6
If additems > 20 Then
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Else
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End If

'FROM HERE
For Each element In ieDoc.querySelectorAll("select")
    If element.Name Like "lineItemCategoryId*" Then
    element.Focus
    If element.Name = valueaux Then
    GoTo nextelement1
    End If
    If element.Name <> valueaux Then
    For i = 6 To 6 + additems
    element.Value = ws2.Range("AE" & i).Value
    If loopexit = i Then Exit For
    Next i
    element.FireEvent ("onchange")
    loopaux = loopaux + 1
    loopexit = loopexit + 1
    valueaux = element.Name
    End If
    If loopaux = additems Then
    GoTo exitfor1
    End If
    
    End If
nextelement1:
Next element
exitfor1:
loopaux = 0
loopexit = 6
iSubcat = 6

'TO HERE. This part of the code repeats four times but taking information from other columns o

'copy to current
For Each element In ieDoc.querySelectorAll("input")
    If InStr(1, element.outerHTML, "javascript:selectAll(this, 'selectedLineItems');") > 0 Then
        element.Click
        element.FireEvent ("onclick")
        GoTo exitfor7
    End If
    Next element
exitfor7:

If additems > 20 Then
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Else
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End If

ieDoc.getElementById("/images/buttons/save.gif").Click

If additems > 20 Then
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Else
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End If


Dim copytocurrent1 As HTMLDivElement
Set copytocurrent1 = ieDoc.getElementById("MI_Column_1")
Dim copytocurrent2 As Object
copytocurrent1.Click

For Each element In ieDoc.querySelectorAll("span.dojoMenuItem2Label")
    If element.innerText Like "Current" Then
        element.Click
        element.FireEvent ("onclick")
        GoTo exitfor8
    End If
Next element
exitfor8:

If additems > 20 Then
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Else
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End If


ieDoc.getElementById("/images/buttons/save.gif").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

ieDoc.getElementById("2473").getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click

If additems > 20 Then
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Else
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End If

UserForm1.Show

Set GMF = Workbooks(GMFname)
GMF.Activate

For Each element In ieDoc.querySelectorAll("select")
    If element.innerText Like "LOW SAVINGS*" Then
        Call Savings
        element.Value = savings_comment
        GoTo exitfor10
    End If
Next element
exitfor10:
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'Repeats las loop five more times for different boxes

ieDoc.getElementById("/images/buttons/save.gif").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'it gets here, does everything in the code and then crashes

End Sub



Public Function IEWindowFromTitle(sTitle As String) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim win As Object, rv As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    For Each win In objShellWindows
        If TypeName(win.document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            If UCase(win.document.Title) = UCase(sTitle) Then
                Set rv = win
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set IEWindowFromTitle = rv

End Function
```

In the code some names have been changed to generic names and some parts that are repeated have been deleted.

```html
Sub automateIE()

Dim wkb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1, ws2, ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("ws1")
    
Dim ieApp As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set ieApp = IEWindowFromTitle("website title")   'this is a formula I'm using from someone else and it's after this code
    If Not ieApp Is Nothing Then
        Set ieDoc = ieApp.document
    End If

ws2.Activate
If ws2.Range("A6").Value <> "" Then
    If ws2.Range("A6").Offset(1).Value = "" Then
        additems = 1
        GoTo add_items                           'if I want to exit the for loop with "Exit For" IE crashes too so I chenged it to GoTo
    ElseIf ws2.Range("A6").Offset(2).Value = "" Then
        additems = 2
        GoTo add_items
    Else
        additems = ws2.Range(Range("A6"), Range("A6").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
        GoTo add_items
    End If
End If

ws3.Activate
If ws3.Range("A6").Value <> "" Then
    If ws3.Range("A6").Offset(1).Value = "" Then
        additems = 1
    ElseIf ws3.Range("A6").Offset(2).Value = "" Then
        additems = 2
    Else
        additems = ws3.Range(Range("A6"), Range("A6").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
    End If
End If


add_items:
Dim additemsbtn As HTMLDivElement
Set additemsbtn = ieDoc.getElementById("MI_AddItem")
Dim aNodeList As Object
Dim itemName As HTMLDivElement
Dim savebtn As HTMLDivElement

additemsbtn.Click
Set aNodeList = ieDoc.querySelectorAll("[dojoinsertionindex]")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Dim repeatadd As Variant
Dim rest As Integer

repeatadd = (additems / 5)
Dim roundvalue() As String
roundvalue() = Split(repeatadd, ",")

If additems < 6 Then
    For i = 0 To additems
        If aNodeList.Item(i).innerText Like additems Then
            aNodeList.Item(i).Click
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Else
    If additems Mod 5 = 0 Then
        For i = 1 To repeatadd
                aNodeList.Item(4).Click
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Next i
    Else
        If additems < 75 Then
            rest = additems Mod 5
            For i = 1 To roundvalue(0)
                aNodeList.Item(4).Click
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Next i
            For i = 0 To rest
                If aNodeList.Item(i).innerText Like rest Then
                    aNodeList.Item(i).Click
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                End If
            Next i
        ElseIf additems >= 75 And additems < 100 Then
            ieDoc.getElementsByName("pageSize")(0).Value = 100
            ieDoc.getElementById("navlist").Click
            rest = additems Mod 5
            For i = 1 To roundvalue(0)
                aNodeList.Item(4).Click
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Next i
            For i = 0 To rest
                If aNodeList.Item(i).innerText Like rest Then
                    aNodeList.Item(i).Click
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If
End If

Dim element As Object
Dim loopaux As Integer
Dim loopexit As Integer
Dim valueaux As String

If additems > 20 Then
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
End If

'FROM HERE
For Each element In ieDoc.querySelectorAll("select")
    If element.Name Like "itemLevelCustomFieldValue*" Then
    Else: GoTo nextelement
    End If
    If element.Value <> "JJTMS" Then
    element.Focus
    element.Value = "something"
    element.FireEvent ("onchange")
    loopaux = loopaux + 1
    If loopaux = additems Then
    GoTo exitfor
    End If
    End If
nextelement:
Next element
exitfor:
loopaux = 0
loopexit = 6
If additems > 20 Then
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Else
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End If

'FROM HERE
For Each element In ieDoc.querySelectorAll("select")
    If element.Name Like "lineItemCategoryId*" Then
    element.Focus
    If element.Name = valueaux Then
    GoTo nextelement1
    End If
    If element.Name <> valueaux Then
    For i = 6 To 6 + additems
    element.Value = ws2.Range("AE" & i).Value
    If loopexit = i Then Exit For
    Next i
    element.FireEvent ("onchange")
    loopaux = loopaux + 1
    loopexit = loopexit + 1
    valueaux = element.Name
    End If
    If loopaux = additems Then
    GoTo exitfor1
    End If
    
    End If
nextelement1:
Next element
exitfor1:
loopaux = 0
loopexit = 6
iSubcat = 6

'TO HERE. This part of the code repeats four times but taking information from other columns o

'copy to current
For Each element In ieDoc.querySelectorAll("input")
    If InStr(1, element.outerHTML, "javascript:selectAll(this, 'selectedLineItems');") > 0 Then
        element.Click
        element.FireEvent ("onclick")
        GoTo exitfor7
    End If
    Next element
exitfor7:

If additems > 20 Then
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Else
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End If

ieDoc.getElementById("/images/buttons/save.gif").Click

If additems > 20 Then
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Else
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End If


Dim copytocurrent1 As HTMLDivElement
Set copytocurrent1 = ieDoc.getElementById("MI_Column_1")
Dim copytocurrent2 As Object
copytocurrent1.Click

For Each element In ieDoc.querySelectorAll("span.dojoMenuItem2Label")
    If element.innerText Like "Current" Then
        element.Click
        element.FireEvent ("onclick")
        GoTo exitfor8
    End If
Next element
exitfor8:

If additems > 20 Then
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Else
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End If


ieDoc.getElementById("/images/buttons/save.gif").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

ieDoc.getElementById("2473").getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click

If additems > 20 Then
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Else
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End If

UserForm1.Show

Set GMF = Workbooks(GMFname)
GMF.Activate

For Each element In ieDoc.querySelectorAll("select")
    If element.innerText Like "LOW SAVINGS*" Then
        Call Savings
        element.Value = savings_comment
        GoTo exitfor10
    End If
Next element
exitfor10:
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'Repeats las loop five more times for different boxes

ieDoc.getElementById("/images/buttons/save.gif").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'it gets here, does everything in the code and then crashes

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is your vba code please? See [mcve]

Comment: Idea - There is `While(True)` in the code.

Comment: @QHarr the code is long.. what part would be better to post? Maybe when I call the internet explorer open instance?

Comment: @Vityata you mean some While loop?

Comment: You have got rid of the reference to the IE instance with Set ieApp = Nothing

Comment: So i need to erase that part of the code?

Comment: Well... yes because it will be out of scope at the end of the sub so dereferenced anyway. You don't need that line. But, I am not sure what you mean by crash?  What you should have is a line before the End Sub saying ieApp.Quit to close the application. If you haven't been closing IE instances over time this may be causing the crash. Open the task manager and see how many IE instances you have running.

Comment: @QHarr I uploaded a screenshot of what I get. I tried with ieApp.Quit but I still have the same problem

Comment: Try to post the code segment which is written after "Set ieApp = Nothing". It can help us to narrow down the issue and find the cause for the issue. 
Also try to make a test with any other machine and check IE get crashed on that machine or not. It can hep us to decide whether issue is machine specific or not.

Comment: @deepak-MSFT I tried in another machine but it's the same. After "set ieApp = Nothing" there's nothing else. I'll post the entire code cause It will be the only way we'll might solve it

Comment: Please do note that when you use `querySelectorAll` using For-Each Loop it will crashes your IE browser. use For Loop instead.